# Using Text.XML.Cursor to get specific HTML table column

Tags: html, parsing, haskell, xpath, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an HTML page using Haskell and `Text.XML.Cursor` package. My goal is to return the third column values in a list. I've spent last 4 hours trying to make it work. However, it seems that I'm unable to understand how XPath and `Text.XML.Cursor` works conceptually.

So the task is:

1. Find `<table class="forumTable">` tag somewhere in the document
2. For every `<tr>` tag in it take **third** `<td>` tag
3. Inside the cell there is a single `<a>` tag, `content` of which I want to add to the list. Not the `href` attribute but the value between `<a>` and `</a>`

To be specific, I am parsing [this link](http://www.sql.ru/forum/sqlru-3-days/2) and I am trying to obtain the value of the column with forum names(next one after the topic).

This is as far as I could get. Seems to be returning all contents of `<a>` tags inside the table

```
findNodes :: Cursor -> [Cursor]
findNodes = element "table" >=> attributeIs "class" "forumTable" &// element "tr" &/ element "td" &/ element "a" >=> child
extractData = T.concat . content
...
let cursor = fromDocument $ parseLBS $ simpleHTTP "http://www.sql.ru/forum/sqlru-3-days/2"
let lines = cursor $// findNodes &| extractData
```

I am seeking for a solution to my problem as well as for an explanation of how this all works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out!

Consider the following input file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Haskell XML Parsing Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="forumTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td> <a href="#1">1</a> </td>
          <td> <a href="#2">2</a> </td>
          <td> <a href="#3">3</a> </td>
          <td> <a href="#4">4</a> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <a href="#5">5</a> </td>
          <td> <a href="#6">6</a> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <a href="#7">7</a> </td>
          <td> <a href="#8">8</a> </td>
          <td> <a href="#9">9</a> </td>
          <td> <a href="#10">10</a> </td>
          <td> <a href="#11">11</a> </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the Haskell code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import Text.XML.Cursor
import Text.XML

select3rd :: Name -> Axis
select3rd name =
    helper . (child >=> element name)
  where
      helper (_:_:x:_) = [x]
      helper _         = []

findNodes :: Cursor -> [Cursor]
findNodes =
    element "table" >=> attributeIs "class" "forumTable"
        &// element "tr" >=> select3rd "td"
        &/ element "a"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    doc <- Text.XML.readFile def "res/test.html"
    let cursor = fromDocument doc
    mapM_ T.putStrLn (cursor $.// findNodes &/ content)
```

It takes some time until you understand how all these operators (`$.//`, `&/`, etc) work, but after reading the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.5.1/docs/Text-XML-Cursor.html) a couple of times and playing around with them, things get better. Also, I suggest a careful reading at the part that explains what a `Cursor` and an `Axis` are.

The code above works as follows (didactically). Firstly, we get in `main` a `cursor` to the root of the document using the provided library functions. Then we compose `cursor`, `findNodes` and `content` together. The operator `$.//` means that `findNodes` must run in the context of the current cursor (`cursor`) and all its descendants. In other words, it simply means that `findNodes` will get access to the whole HTML tree. Give it a try and use `$/` instead of `$.//`. You'll notice that `findNodes` won't find the `<table>` element using `element "table"` because `<table>` is not directly below `<html>` (which is the place that `cursor` currently points to). Then, in `findNodes`, we compose `element "table"` and `attributeIs "class" "forumTable"` using the `>=>` operator because the function in the right hand side (rhs) must execute on the `Axis` returned by the left hand side (lhs).

After that, we use the `&//` operator to filter the descendant `<tr>`s inside the `<table>`. As before, If we had used only `&/`, the `<tr>`s wouldn't be found because there is an enclosing `<tbody>` tag and `&/` only look the immediate descendants (or children). Notice that when we have a `Cursor` in the lhs, the operators begin with `$`, while when we have an `Axis`, they begin with `&`. Finally, we have the `select3rd` axis, which allows the named selection of the third child of a node when it exists. We use it to select the third `<td>` in each `<tr>`. Hopepully, by now, it should be easy to understand how it works.

The code in your question has a call to `child` in the end of `findNodes` that uses the `>=>` operator. As long as you also change the `&/` before `content` to `>=>`, you can keep that call (both implementations are equivalent).

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think you can work with axis like with lists!